# Why am i getting NoSuchElementException error in my class

Tags: java, android, list, object, arraylist

I have this class who is supposed open a file with a nr of questions in it with a nr of answer.
The problem is when it get's in that for to write in the ArrayList. I have tried all type of ArrayLists,LinkedLists, even vectors.
The first parts of the file, like the question and nr of answer, it takes it without any problem. But when i want to store those answers in a list so i can save that list in an object it won't work.

If anyone could help with this or knows a better method so save an unknown nr of string into an object list it would be epic.

The file format is:

```
A question,3,yes,no,maybe
Another question,4,yes,maybe,no,why not
```

my class:

```
public class GetSurvey {
public static String intrebare;
static int raspunsuri;
public static int i = 1;
static String holder;
//static String[] rasp = new String[250];
static List<String> rasp = new LinkedList<String>();
public static SurveyClass[] obj = new SurveyClass[250];
public static void loadSurvey()
{
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+File.separator+"Survey.dat");
    if(!file.exists()){
        try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    if(file.exists()){
        try {
            Scanner read = new Scanner(file);
            read.useDelimiter(",");
            while (read.hasNext())
                {
                    intrebare = read.next();
                    String raspunsuri1 = read.next();
                    //Log.w("Date",String.valueOf(raspunsuri));
                    //obj[i].setNrRasp(raspunsuri);

                    for(int j = 0;j < 3;j++)
                    {
                        Log.w("Date",String.valueOf(j));
                        rasp.add(j,read.next());

                    }
                    String[] stringArr = rasp.toArray(new String[rasp.size()]);
                    Log.w("Date",stringArr[i]);

                    //obj[i].setRaspunsuri(rasp);
                    rasp.clear();
                    i++;
                }
            } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using read.next() 3 times inside your loop, so that means that you get past the end of the input, hence NoSuchElementException.

Use it only once and assign it to a local variable inside the loop, so you can use that value whenever you need it again later in the loop.

Comment: Ty, you are right ! Can't believe i didn't noticed that.
I'm just going to get the entire lines from the file and work on them, instead of getting word with word.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you should perform only one `read.next()` inside your `while(read.hasNext())` Loop . Analyse the read element, perform the neccessary task and rerun the loop until  `while(read.hasNext())` fails. This way you can be sure you'll never perform a read beyond the size of your List.

Comment: Ty for the help, not i get it ;)